# There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query. Severity 17 State 130

Tags: sql-server, database

This is the error coming when I am executing any query in my database. Please tell the required how to get rid of this Error.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: please add more details like amount of memory in your system ?

Comment: And also what is configured maximum memory, is there something else running in the same server, is it always the same query that causes the error, does everything else work ok...

Comment: There is no way to answer this with so little info. What's the server configuration, which query/action is causing it, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the lack of memory resources. Try to follow the below steps,

- Right click on the selected server and select Properties
- Select Memory from the left pane
- Increase the value for Maximum Server Memory(in MB).

Even before doing this exercise, try to see what exactly is causing. Few of the reasons are,

1. The physical memory is completely used and no longer available further for SQL Server
2. SQL Server engine's Max. memory allocation has been reached the limit.
3. Virtual memory is full

First of all find out which processes are consuming memory, if any tools or application processes outside of your SQL Server consuming and then you can close or kill the process using the Task Manager.

Run below command to find out memory Status

```
DBCC MEMORYSTATUS
```

You can also run below commands to flush the memory

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

Comment: If with "2147483647" you're refering to max server memory setting, it's a bad practice. One should always set this to leave some memory for the OS at least, even if it's a dedicated server. The advice to drop the buffers is not well founded also, it's more dangerous than helping. This kind of problems could be often linked to a particular query (or log shipping or something like this), so this should be looked at first.

Comment: Thanks dean. I would rather take my suggestion back